# Newlines and null-terminated string in assembly

Tags: string, assembly, low-level, null-terminated

I am new to assembly and i was looking at a hello world program:

```
section .data
    hello:     db 'Hello, World!',10    ; 'Hello, World!' plus a linefeed character
    helloLen:  equ $-hello             ; Length of the 'Hello world!' string

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax,4            ; The system call for write (sys_write)
    mov ebx,1            ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
    mov ecx,hello        ; Put the offset of hello in ecx
    mov edx,helloLen     ; helloLen is a constant, so we don't need to say
                         ;  mov edx,[helloLen] to get it's actual value
    int 80h              ; Call the kernel
    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return "code" of 0 (no error)
    int 80h;
```

My question is regarding the string `db 'Hello, World!',10`. What i understand is that this is the "Hello, World!" string terminated by a linefeed, but from what i know strings have to be terminated by a null character, and what i've learned from another source regarding that is to create strings as `db "Hello, World!,0`.

How do you add a newline/linefeed at the end (or inside) of a string and also the null terminator at the very end?

(I do understand that, in the given program, the code is printed using the given length and that that is an option, but null terminated strings seem better, having to give the length for every string you'll write ever doesn't seem very good)

Comment: You can add a `, 10, 0` if you want but then you need to correct the `helloLen` to not include that.

Comment: thank you, i had no idea you could add multiple commas; does that mean you could do something like `db 'Line 1', 10, 'Line 2', 0`?

Comment: Yes you can add as many elements as you want. Even if you couldn't you could still use multiple `db` directives on separate lines.

Comment: Most assemblers allow to define more than one element in one statement.
String termination depends on the service which is fed with the string. Functions which manipulate with files require that the file name is **NUL-terminated**. WriteString in DOS wants **$-terminated** string. Linux *sys_write* needs to provide **string netto size** in a separate parameter.

Comment: In general, when asking an assembly question, include tags for the assembler you are using (if the question is related to assembler syntax or directives, as this is), the target architecture (if the question is related to the behavior of the code or individual instructions), and operating system (if using system calls or other OS-specific features).  This looks like code for the nasm assembler to run on the x86 architecture on the Linux OS, but please verify.

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you for the information, i'll keep that in mind. Unfortunately, the code i was looking through was online and there was no specified assembler nor architecture, the question was a generic one (if it is different based on the specified criteria please do correct me). As for what i use, i am using nasm on Windows 10 with an x86_64 architecture

Comment: Okay, so then this code is not going to be useful to you, as it is written for Linux.  The system call interface on Linux (with `int 80h`) is completely different from Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I accidentally overlooked your last sentence, so the first part of this answer is explaining what you probably already know.  I'll just leave it in case it is helpful to some future reader.)

> from what i know strings have to be terminated by a null character

It's true that a null terminator is a very *common* way to mark the end of a string, and that many functions are designed to work with strings in this form; e.g. all the `str*` functions in the standard C library.  It's common enough that people often use the word "string" to mean "null-terminated string" without further clarification.

But the `write` system call is not one of those functions.  It doesn't rely on a null terminator to mark the end of the data to be written; rather, it uses the length argument (which you have put in the `edx` register) to know how many bytes from memory should be written to the file descriptor.  If you think about it, it has to be this way: if `write` used null-terminated strings, then it would be impossible to use it to write a binary file that needs to contain null bytes.

So in your program, since the only thing you do with your `hello` message is to pass it to the `write` system call, there is no need to include a terminating null byte.  It would just waste a byte of memory.

---

If you *do* want to include a terminating null byte (perhaps because you want to use this string with `str*` functions, `printf`, etc), then simply append a 0:

```
hello:     db 'Hello, World!', 10, 0
```

You didn't mention which assembler you are using, but it looks like nasm.  The nasm documentation is pretty complete, and it explains that the [`db` directive](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.1) can accept an arbitrary list of strings and numerical expressions.

Note that, if you keep the `helloLen` definition below, then that length would *include* the terminating null, which is likely not what you want.  But if you were using functions that detect length by the null terminator, then you probably wouldn't need `helloLen` at all.

Comment: You can do `foo: db 'hi', 10` / `len equ $-foo` / `db 0` to put a 0 terminator *after* the part you're calculating length for, if you want an assemble-time-constant `strlen` for an implicit-length string constant.  Or `len equ $-foo - 1` to count one less, or `len equ ($-1)-foo` which is equivalent but reads to humans as taking the end position as one byte earlier.